# Any relationship between rank and operator norm of a Hermitian matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, random-matrices, hermitian-matrices

In 'Topics in Random Matrix Theory' by Terence Tao, Exercise 2.4.3 and Exercise 2.4.4 deals with the stability of the empirical spectral distribution (ESD) w.r.t. some perturbations:

Let $M_{n}$ and $N_{n}$ be sequences of random Hermitian matrix ensembles. Let $\mu$ a (deterministic) probability measure.

> Exercise 2.4.3. If $\mu_{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} M_{n}} \rightarrow \mu$ a.s. and $\frac{1}{n^2} \| N_{n} \|_{F}^2  \rightarrow 0$ a.s., then $\mu_{ \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} ( M_{n} + N_{n})} \rightarrow \mu$ a.s..

> Exercise 2.4.4. If $\mu_{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} M_{n}} \rightarrow \mu$ a.s. and $\frac{1}{n} \operatorname{rank} (N_{n}) \rightarrow 0$ a.s., then $\mu_{ \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} ( M_{n} + N_{n})} \rightarrow \mu$ a.s..

I solved Exercise 2.4.3., which was just a corollary of Lemma 2.4.3. The hint for Exercise 2.4.4 was to use the Weyl inequalities instead of the Wielandt-Hoffman inequality. But Weyl inequalities contain terms of 'operator norm', not 'rank'. Some identities I recall are
$$ \| A \|_{op} \le \| A \|_{F} \le \sqrt{\operatorname{rank} (A)} \| A\|_{op}$$
for Hermitian matrix $A$, and
$$ \| A \|_{op} = \sigma(A)$$
for diagonalizable matrix $A$, where $\sigma(A)$ is the spectral radius of $A$.

My questions are:

(1) Any relationship between rank and operator norm of a Hermitian matrix?

(2) Does the assumption $\frac{1}{n} \operatorname{rank}(N_{n}) \rightarrow 0$ a.s. implies $\|M_{n} \|_{op} = o(n)$?

Comment: The Weyl inequalities offer bounds in terms of singular values, and $\text{rank}(M) \le k$ iff $\sigma_{k+1} = 0$.

Comment: Do you mean should I use singular values instead of eigenvaues?

Comment: Ah, I missed that your matrices were Hermitian. In that case they're basically the same (up to sign).

Comment: I didn't think about the fact that rank = # of nonzero eigenvalues for Hermitian matrices. Thank you.